# Measure total memory usage of python process that processing pool

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I'm running a python script that uses concurrent.futures.processPool. I would like to get an idea of what the *peak* memory usage is including all the child processes.

There are obviously many linux tools for measuring memory usage, but I'd like to know if there's anything that correctly compacts child processes and accounts for copy-on-write

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `tracemalloc` https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html

```py
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()

# do some work

current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
print(f"current: {current}, peak: {peak}")
```

Comment: Will this be able to correctly sum-up the memory allocated by the child processes? I'd have thought that peak would just be calculated over the original process and it wouldn't be able to detect that the other processes are allocating after it has forked. I guess I could print this out on each child and sum it up, but I feel like I need more information then about when specific peaks are for each worker process